# IntelliJ Idea: Imported project fails compilation due to git change markers

Tags: git, intellij-idea, markers

I am trying to import a project from a locally folder into which I have checked out a project from bitbucket.

With a little effort, I could set the project work on gradle and get the IDE to show all the tasks.

However when I try to compile the project, all my files contain the following string at the top:

```
<<<<<<< Updated upstream
```

and the entire file. THis is followed by the pair of lines:
    =======
    =======

and then the entire class. At the end of this java file are two lines

```
>>>>>>> Stashed changes
>>>>>>> Stashed changes
```

Does anybody know what is happening here? How can I get Idea to avoid placing those git markers?

Comment: This looks like a merge conflict. Are you in the middle of a merge? Perhaps the merge was motivated by you unstashing stashed changes and they were now in conflict with the latest changes "updated upstream"?

Comment: If the entire files are marked like this then most likely you have a line ending problem that provoked the merge conflict.

Comment: The last I know,I did not make any changes. So this project is as fresh as just drawn off the shelf.

In either case, what remedies do I have?

Comment: Resolve the merge conflict, if that's what it is. Issue a git merge and see what it says. Also try `git mergetool` to see if your external merge tool is helpful.

Comment: Merged all my changes. But when I close and reopen the IDEA IDE, the lines reappear. How can I get over this?

Comment: Sorry, don't know, I've never used IDEA. If that IDE is the one adding those conflicts you probably need help from someone who knows how and why it does that.